# Selenium で Chrome をモバイルモードで開くと位置情報を変更できません

Tags: python, selenium, chromedriver

SeleniumでChromeをモバイルモードで開いて位置情報を変更したいのですが、
`MobileEmulation`設定をすると`GeoLocation`設定が無視されてしまいます。

MobileEmulationなしだと位置情報の変更はできているので、
モバイルエミュレータを有効にすると位置情報の設定はできないということでしょうか？

`options=options.add_argment("auto-open-devtools-for-tabs")`を加え、PCモードで位置情報設定をしたうえで <kbd>F5</kbd> を押せばモバイルモードに切り替えられるかと思いましたが、DevToolsをハンドリングできず、モバイルモードに切り替えることができませんでした。

実現方法があればご教示いただけますと幸いです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

**現状のソースコード:**

```
options = Options()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=Exefile,options=options)
driver.execute_cdp_cmd(         
        'Browser.grantPermissions',
        {
            'origin': "https://www.google.com/",
            'permissions': ['geolocation']
        },
)
driver.execute_cdp_cmd(         
        'Emulation.setGeolocationOverride',
        {
        'latitude': 26.2125,
        'longitude': 127.68111,
        'accuracy': 100,
        },
)
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
gmb_name = driver.find_element_by_class_name("gLFyf")
gmb_name.send_keys("焼肉")
gmb_name.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

Comment: chromedriver起動時に対象機種とか許可など設定して渡しておく感じの記事がそれぞれありますので、調べてみてください。[Python+Selenium+Chromeでスマホモードに切り替える方法](https://qiita.com/momotar47279337/items/dde5c57904b8d4c0e4aa), [Mobile Emulation](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/mobile-emulation), [Options().add_experimental_option does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65828238/9014308), [How to allow or deny notification geo-location microphone camera pop up](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48007699/9014308)

Comment: ありがとうございます！参考にしてみます！

Comment: 近々リリース予定のSelenium 4だと出来るような記事がありますね。4系のIsuueを探すとかrc1を試すとかしてみては？ [Selenium 4 With Python: All You Need To Know](https://www.lambdatest.com/blog/selenium-with-python/), [Downloads](https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/)